# Configuration constant variables in Android

Tags: java, android, configuration

Sometimes I need to introduce a configuration const variable into my class but it's messing with the rest const varibales which are used in logic of app. For other java apps I use `Spring Framework` to reach that point, but now I developing for Android...

What is the best way to introduce such const configuration variable into my class in Android app?

Now I've got:

```
public final class ScoresTableComponent extends Activity
{
    private static boolean PRINT_SHORT_DATE_IF_TODAY = false;

    private static final Typeface TYPEFACE_FOR_STATS = Typeface.DEFAULT;
    private static final int TEXT_SIZE_IN_DP = 17;
    private static final float TEXT_Y_ORIGIN_IN_DP = 27;
    private static final int TOP_MARGIN_IN_DP = 0;

    ...

}
```

Where `PRINT_SHORT_DATE_IF_TODAY` is configuration variable.

Comment: Can you give some examples ofthe configuration variables you are talking about?

Comment: Yep. I have provided an example.

Comment: Are these "set-once-at-startup" or shall they be mutable at runtime? I guess http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref is what you'll want.

Comment: They all are "set-once-at-startup". But they have different purpose...

Comment: Have you found a solution that suites your needs, meanwhile?

Comment: @Fildor nope, I just left it as it was :)